# Page, sort and filter on relational table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So my requirement is to use a stored proc to page, sort and filter my data. The data will then match up to a table.

When i sort and filter i should pass in the relevant column name. The issue i am having is some of my columns are counts from nested select statements so i cant order by those columns. My sql is not that strong so any help would be great.

So just to add i use a custom type to pass an array of guids to the proc.

```
CREATE TYPE GUIDArray AS table(Item varchar(MAX))
```

Currently the procedure looks like this:

```
USE [Test]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_CheckInsPerUserReport]    Script Date: 24/03/2018 00:36:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


/*CREATE TYPE GUIDArray AS table(Item varchar(MAX))*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckInsPerUserReport]
@UserIds as GUIDArray READONLY,
@dateStart varchar(max),
@dateEnd varchar(max),
@SortColumn VARCHAR(50),
@SortOrder VARCHAR(50),
@PageNumber INT,
@PageSize INT,
@SearchTerm VARCHAR(500),
@SearchColumn VARCHAR(100)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @StartRow INT
DECLARE @EndRow INT

-- calculate the starting and ending of records
SET @SortColumn = LOWER(ISNULL(@SortColumn, ''))
SET @SortOrder = LOWER(ISNULL(@SortOrder, ''))
SET @StartRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize
SET @EndRow = (@PageNumber * @PageSize)+1

;WITH CTEResult AS (

       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'username' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN username END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'username' AND @SortOrder='desc') THEN username END DESC,

        CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'email' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN email END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'email' AND @SortOrder='desc') THEN email END DESC
       ) AS RowNumber,
       COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount,
       u.username, 
       u.email, 
       /* Get the roles and concat into one string. */ 
       (SELECT ( Stuff((SELECT ', ' + [name] 
                        FROM   [aspnetroles] 
                        WHERE  [id] IN (SELECT [roleid] 
                                        FROM   [aspnetuserroles] 
                                        WHERE  [userid] = u.id) 
                        FOR xml path('')), 1, 2, '') )) AS Roles, 
       /* Get the users team */ 
       (SELECT [name] 
        FROM   [teams] 
        WHERE  [id] = u.team_id)                        AS Team, 
       /* Get the soft checkin count */ 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   [checkins] 
        WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
               AND [inat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [outat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [inat] >= CAST(@dateStart AS datetime) 
               AND [outat] < Dateadd(day, 1, CAST(@dateEnd AS datetime))
               AND ( [state] = 1 
                      OR [state] = 3 ))                 AS SoftCheckins, 
       /* Get the hard checkin count */ 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   [checkins] 
        WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
               AND [hardinat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [hardoutat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [hardinat] >= CAST(@dateStart AS datetime)
               AND [hardoutat] < Dateadd(day, 1, CAST(@dateEnd AS datetime)) 
               AND [hardstate] = 3)                     AS HardCheckins, 
       /* get all checkins for total */ 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   [checkins] 
        WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
               AND [inat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [outat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [inat] >= CAST(@dateStart AS datetime) 
               AND [outat] < Dateadd(day, 1,CAST(@dateEnd AS datetime)) 
               AND ( [state] = 1 
                      OR [state] = 3 )) 
       + (SELECT Count(*) 
          FROM   [checkins] 
          WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
                 AND [hardinat] IS NOT NULL 
                 AND [hardoutat] IS NOT NULL 
                 AND [hardinat] >= CAST(@dateStart AS datetime)
                 AND [hardoutat] < Dateadd(day, 1, CAST(@dateEnd AS datetime)) 
                 AND [hardstate] = 3)                   AS TotalCheckins 
FROM   [aspnetusers] AS u 
WHERE  u.id IN (SELECT Item FROM @UserIds)
AND (@searchColumn = 'userName' AND u.username LIKE '%%'))

SELECT RowNumber, TotalCount, username as UserName, email as Email, Roles as Role, Team, SoftCheckins, HardCheckins, TotalCheckins
FROM CTEResult
WHERE RowNumber > @StartRow AND RowNumber < @EndRow
ORDER BY RowNumber



GO
```

I have found a lot of resources on handling paging, sorting and filtering. However they all use the columns on the current table, since i need to sort and filter on the columns with there own select like "SoftCheckins" the examples did not give me the help i needed.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending more time on this it was just an issue of scope. I separated my select for the main chunk of data from the rownumber. Although i will need to make sure this does not effect performance much.

```
USE [Test]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_CheckInsPerUserReport]    Script Date: 24/03/2018 00:36:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


/*CREATE TYPE GUIDArray AS table(Item varchar(MAX))*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckInsPerUserReport]
@UserIds as GUIDArray READONLY,
@dateStart varchar(max),
@dateEnd varchar(max),
@SortColumn VARCHAR(50) = '',
@SortOrder VARCHAR(50) = '',
@PageNumber INT,
@PageSize INT
/*@SearchTerm VARCHAR(500),*/
/*@SearchColumn VARCHAR(100)*/
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @query as nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @StartRow INT
DECLARE @EndRow INT

-- calculate the starting and ending of records
SET @SortColumn = LOWER(ISNULL(@SortColumn, ''))
SET @SortOrder = LOWER(ISNULL(@SortOrder, ''))
SET @StartRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize
SET @EndRow = (@PageNumber * @PageSize)+1

;WITH CTEResult AS (

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'username' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN username END ASC,
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'username' AND @SortOrder='desc') THEN username END DESC,

            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'email' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN email END ASC,
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'email' AND @SortOrder='desc') THEN email END DESC,

            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'softcheckins' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN SoftCheckins END ASC,
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'softcheckins' AND @SortOrder='desc') THEN SoftCheckins END DESC,

            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'totalcheckins' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN TotalCheckins END ASC,
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'totalcheckins' AND @SortOrder='desc') THEN TotalCheckins END DESC,

            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'hardcheckins' AND @SortOrder='asc') THEN HardCheckins END ASC,
            CASE WHEN (@SortColumn = 'hardcheckins' AND @SortOrder='desc') THEN HardCheckins END DESC
        ) AS RowNumber, username, email, Roles, Team , SoftCheckins, HardCheckins, TotalCheckins,
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            u.username, 
            u.email,
            /* Get the roles and concat into one string. */ 
       (SELECT ( Stuff((SELECT ', ' + [name] 
                        FROM   [aspnetroles] 
                        WHERE  [id] IN (SELECT [roleid] 
                                        FROM   [aspnetuserroles] 
                                        WHERE  [userid] = u.id) 
                        FOR xml path('')), 1, 2, '') )) AS Roles, 
       /* Get the users team */ 
       (SELECT [name] 
        FROM   [teams] 
        WHERE  [id] = u.team_id)                        AS Team, 
       /* Get the soft checkin count */ 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   [checkins] 
        WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
               AND [inat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [outat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [inat] >= CAST('02/24/2018 00:53:52' AS datetime) 
               AND [outat] < Dateadd(day, 1, CAST('03/24/2018 00:00:00' AS datetime))
               AND ( [state] = 1 OR [state] = 3 )) AS SoftCheckins, 
       /* Get the hard checkin count */ 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   [checkins] 
        WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
               AND [hardinat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [hardoutat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [hardinat] >= CAST('02/24/2018 00:53:52' AS datetime)
               AND [hardoutat] < Dateadd(day, 1, CAST('03/24/2018 00:00:00' AS datetime)) 
               AND [hardstate] = 3) AS HardCheckins, 
       /* get all checkins for total */ 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   [checkins] 
        WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
               AND [inat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [outat] IS NOT NULL 
               AND [inat] >= CAST('02/24/2018 00:53:52' AS datetime) 
               AND [outat] < Dateadd(day, 1,CAST('03/24/2018 00:00:00' AS datetime)) 
               AND ( [state] = 1 
                      OR [state] = 3 )) 
       + (SELECT Count(*) 
          FROM   [checkins] 
          WHERE  [user_id] = u.id 
                 AND [hardinat] IS NOT NULL 
                 AND [hardoutat] IS NOT NULL 
                 AND [hardinat] >= CAST('02/24/2018 00:53:52' AS datetime)
                 AND [hardoutat] < Dateadd(day, 1, CAST('03/24/2018 00:00:00' AS datetime)) 
                 AND [hardstate] = 3) AS TotalCheckins 
            FROM [aspnetusers] AS u 
            WHERE  u.id IN (SELECT Item FROM @UserIds)
        ) as d  
) 

SELECT RowNumber, TotalCount, username as UserName, email as Email, Roles as Role, Team, SoftCheckins, HardCheckins, TotalCheckins
FROM CTEResult
WHERE RowNumber > @StartRow AND RowNumber < @EndRow
ORDER BY RowNumber


GO
```